# glDrawPixels in grayscale?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an image that I'm rendering like this:

```
glDrawPixels(image->width, image->height, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->imageData);
```

Is there anyway I can draw it in grayscale instead (without loading it into a texture first)? I don't care if only, say, the blue component is used for the gray value rather than the L2 norm or something, I just need a quick and dirty output.

GL_LUMINANCE would be great, except that it won't work on a 3-channel image.

---

@timday:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A perverse idea for you to try, and I've no idea if it'll work:

```
glPixelZoom(1.0f/3.0f,1.0f);
glDrawPixels(3*width,height,GL_LUMINANCE,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,data);
```

ie treat your 3-channel image as being a 1-channel (grayscale) image 3 times as wide, and compensate for this by squishing the width using the x zoom factor.  I believe GL always does nearest-neighbour sampling for zoomed glDrawPixels, so it ought to consistently pick out the same component from each triple of samples, as you require.

Comment: Oh my God..... I can't believe that works! It sort of splits the image in half, and one side grainier than the other, but it works.

Comment: Could be something to do with the precision with which 1.0/3.0 is maintained internally (especially if it works OK up to a certain size).  I'd suggest adjusting the ratio very slightly or using a 4-bytes-per-pixel format and a zoom factor of 0.25.